# What should we do about en masse resurrection of old questions?

Tags: discussion

We now have a Kabuto on the main site, who has already resurrected a dozen *very* old questions, with unhelpful answers. (Those who don't follow Naruto won't get the Edo Tensei reference, sorry about that.)

From the answers posted, it appears that the said user looks at this site as a discussion board, which it is not. Not targeting the specific user, but what is the right approach to deal with it?

It is impractical to post a comment on every answer telling them to stop, besides diamond moderators have already deleted a few answers, thus preventing comments (but without commenting why the answer was deleted - or at least I don't see it).

Comment: Later this evening (say, 6 hours or so) I'll be on chat, will you be on to provide some more details?

Comment: May not be necessary. I was referring to the answers by user brianahj. Logged in this morning and was surprised to see almost the whole first page filled with Naruto questions. Turns out they are just old questions which got bumped because of new answers by this user.

Comment: PS: Posting *good* answers to old questions is definitely encouraged, but these "answers" were mostly just comments or copied the points from other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Let the users of the community decide if they're good or bad.

New users might not always know (or take time to read) the rules, but we shouldn't discourage them when they make mistakes. If a new user leaves bad/low quality answers, it's leave a comment explaining why and give them some tips to help them along (e.g. point to the [help](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help) page).

But if it persists despite multiple interventions, a downvote will suffice to send a message.

If the answer is not an answer just flag it for the mods.

Afterall, we were all new users at one time.

Comment: Yeah, but when more than a dozen old questions make it to the front page, it pushes other questions down to the next page. Even deleting the "bumping" answer doesn't seem to restore it. Besides, I did not ask for "punishing" the user, just asked how to deal with it.

Comment: I don't believe this to be a something that needs much attention. Sure the front page might be full of old naruto questions. But what of it? If someone is tired of naruto questions they can always filter it out using the "add an ignored tag" feature on the sidebar (on the main and question pages). If you're think you're missing out on new questions, you can always make or [feed](http://anime.stackexchange.com/feeds) for it or [sort tagged questions by newest](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest).

Comment: @Krazer It gives the impression that Naruto is the only thing we talk about here to new users. If I saw the front page as an unregistered user as it is right now ([All but one question is Naruto](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a6DME.png)), I probably wouldn't be interested in participating. That isn't to say that there's anything wrong with Naruto, but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: @LoganM I understand the sentiment, but no one can deny the fact of Naruto. This is definitely something the community needs to work on... but aside from certain titles, there are not many mainstream or long running popular anime/manga to ask questions about. But I do admit we need to start working on our site image... but the question is how and where to go?

Comment: @Krazer Why should I filter out a tag and miss all the new questions, just to skip some old questions? Also, what if the user digs out several questions from various different tags? Should I ignore every tag, just because a newbie doesn't know to read the site guidelines before posting? Sure, everyone is a new user at some time, but every new user doesn't start by trolling the site. I certainly did not, and I know dozens of users who did not. You are effectively saying that if someone is driving on the wrong side, then you should ignore them and take another route!